# Hiding the keyboard when you rotate the phone

Tags: android

I create `EditText` element in `DialogFragment`. Then I set focus on this field and appear keyboard. When I rotate the telephone the keyboard hides.

What should I do to keyboard was visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```

in the manifest under the activity this EditText is like this

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivityWhereEditTextIs"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize" >
```

`stateUnchanged` will make sure that the state of keyboard is same as it was in earlier state.

**FROM CODE**

Use this where you need to show the keyboard. This depends on how you are handling the rotation. If your activity is being recreated use this in `onCreate()` otherwise use in `onconfigurationchanged()`

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
keyboard.showSoftInput(mEditText, 0);
```

Comment: It should work. let me edit my answer so that you can do it by code too.

Comment: For the DialogFragment it is the one way for save  keyboard visible?

Comment: Depends where do you want, you need to put that code there. But try the first part (from manifest) first